# ClickOnce deployed Lightswitch application (Out-Of-Browser) white screen

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch application that is deployed Out-Of-Browser using ClickOnce.

When a user installs and starts the application, a window opens and I can see Silverlight loading the XAP file (it shows the percentages).

Then, the window content just goes white.

**How can I debug that?** How can I get an error message to know what's the cause of the error?

Does Lightswitch write some log, or can I configure it to do so?

I only have the binaries. I can re-configure and re-zip the XAP file, but I cannot re-compile the code or execute the code in Visual Studio.

Here's my config: Windows Server 2012 x64, SQL Server 2008 Express x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I needed to install **WCF HTTP Activation** for some component of LightSwitch to work.

Just go to `Server Manager`, `Add Features`, then click through until you're at the feature page, then select `HTTP Activation` in the `.NET 3.5` or `.NET 4.5` nodes.